# Docker container returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on browser

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker images like this:

```
FROM XXXXXX.com/base-images/dotnet-6.0-sdk as build

WORKDIR /source

COPY ./nuget.config ./nuget.config
COPY ./OrderAPI.sln ./OrderAPI.sln


COPY ./src/*/*.csproj ./
RUN for file in *.csproj; do test "$file" && mkdir -p "src/${file%.*}/" && mv "$file" "src/${file%.*}/"; done

COPY ./tests/*/*.csproj ./
RUN for file in *.csproj; do test "$file" && mkdir -p "tests/${file%.*}/" && mv "$file" "tests/${file%.*}/"; done

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build src/OrderAPI/OrderAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS test
RUN dotnet test OrderAPI.sln

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish OrderAPI.sln -c Release -o /app

#FROM base AS final
FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/base-images/dotnet-6.0-aspnet as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "./OrderAPI.dll"]
```

after i run this command: `docker run --name orderapi  --publish 5000:5000 orderapi`  container is running as:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
c2a81975681c   orderapi   "dotnet ./Orde…"   35 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   orderapi
```

from inside the container I can see the swagger url with `curl http://localhost:5000/swagger/ui/index.html` but from browser I'm getting localhost `didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

the port 5000 is not used by any other process
I also tried with exposing other ports, but still have the same problem on browser and it doesn't work. I tried:

- 127.0.0.1:5000/swagger/ui/index.html
- 0.0.0.0:5000/swagger/ui/index.html
- http://localhost:5000/swagger/ui/index.html

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings? which operating system are you using?